# Python 3 - Saving a google spreadsheet as a csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, google-docs

I am trying to save a private google spreadsheet into a csv. I have found another thread which has addressed this ([Download a spreadsheet from Google Docs using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287651/download-a-spreadsheet-from-google-docs-using-python)), however the answers date back to 2012. There is a solution which I have tried to used, but I am running into errors. This is the code that I am currently using

```
import csv
import gspread

// used the actual username, password and doc-id in the python script
username = "username"
password = "password"
docid = "doc-id"

client = gspread.login(username, password)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(docid)

for i, worksheet in enumerate(spreadsheet.worksheets()):
    filename = docid + '-worksheet' + str(i) + '.csv'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

This is the error that IDLE is throwing up

```
writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

As you must have realized, I am pretty much new to python and I am trying to solve this problem. Can anyone point out what the issue with the code that I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, open the file in text mode, and set `newline` to `''` to let the CSV writer control what newlines are written:

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Amazing speed of the answer. Thanks a ton. :D.

Answer (score 0):

**(Jul 2016)** The use of GData is outdated when accessing Google Sheets files now. The current modern way to export a Google Sheet as CSV is by using the Google Drive API. I wrote a [blogpost](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html) with a Python 2+3 code sample that shows you how to do this. Also check the other thread where I added an answer more modern than 2012. With that update, this thread should be marked as a duplicate of that other one. To access Google Sheets from Python in a more general sense, check [this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37868852/305689) to a related question.