# Accessing the data from Google sheets as data base for dialogflow

Tags: python, json, node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a chatbot using dialog flow , for this i have my data in excel sheet and i want to use this as a database source for my bot! Is there any way that i can do it without writing several intents?

Comment: You may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690138/how-do-i-access-read-write-to-google-sheets-spreadsheets-with-python

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow has no direct connection to Google Sheets or the Sheets API. If you want to use a Sheet as the source of some answers, you will need to integrate it through Dialogflow Intents and a Fulfillment webhook.

In your webhook, you will need to make calls to the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) to get the info you want to be able to return.