# How to specify sheet when importing a file from google drive into bigquery

Tags: google-drive-api, google-bigquery

When I create a new table in bigquery by importing data from an excel file in my google drive I am unable to specify the sheet from which I want the data to be from.
I've already been here:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/bigquery-integrates-with-google-drive
But it wasn't very helpful since it doesn't even mention the possibility of a file having multiple sheets (which is basically 99% of excel files)
Has anyone run into the same issue, how have you solved it?
Thanks!

Comment: Right now BigQuery can only read the first sheet. Reading the whole spreadsheet is tracked by https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905674.

Comment: @HuaZhang thanks for your reply :) I'll follow the issue on the link you sent.

Answer (score 2):

You can now specify the sheet and/or range of a Google Sheet in the new BigQuery UI which you would like to use as your federated data source.

[image: Specify sheet range]

From Google:

*Optionally indicate which sheet and cell range in the Google Sheets spreadsheet to create a table from. You can specifiy:
[sheet_title] for the whole sheet, or
[sheet_title]![top_left_cell_id]:[bottom_right_cell_id]for a rectangular cell range in a sheet, such as "Sheet1!A1:B20".
When this is not specified, the first sheet in the spreadsheet is used.*

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentioned and as it explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive),  BigQuery only imports the first worksheet of the spreadsheet.  One more complicated way to import the data  from Google Drive to BigQuery is to use worksheet ID (gid) in Google-drive SDK to import the excel file different spreadsheets(like the way that has been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287651/download-a-spreadsheet-from-google-docs-using-python)) and then use [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) to export data to your desired table.