# Download google sheet, require me to login first

Tags: python

I am trying to download a google spreadsheet in the form of CSV.
But the script will always redirect me to login page even I provided the user name and password. Any suggestion to fix this?

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

response = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1Kwim1GF0SXx24kN8LycaYF6LUsJAIAm6FkPStDqDoNE&output=csv',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx'))
data=response.content
csv_file = open(r"C:\google_sheet\bills.csv", "w")
csv_file.write("%s" % data)
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: You might need to use selenium to log in?

Answer (score 0):

To do this without google python client, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287651/download-a-spreadsheet-from-google-docs-using-python).

But you may want to use the [google cloud python client](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python).  Using the client, you would want to access the **google drive api**; the sheets api is more about manipulating sheets so don't use that.

Follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) to (1) get connectivity in the form of a service object and (2) list the ids for your spreadsheets.

To authenticate your service object, you'll need to generate a credentials file.  Then you'll use the service object to make your api calls (listing and downloading).

With service object and file id in hand, you [download a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) as csv like so:

```
file_id = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo'
request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                             mimeType='text/csv')
with open('/path/to/outfile.csv', 'w') as fh:
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```